# how to correctly store shared data via a variable in a module

Tags: node.js

My application has some shared data in database, instead of reading them for each request, I want to read them out only once and store them as an array in a module.  However, I am not sure how to do this correctly, any helps will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var isStored = false;
var isStroing = false;
var allRecords = [];

function getSharedData(callback) {
   if (isStored) {
      callback(null, allRecords);
      return;
   }
   if (isStoring) {  // check to see if other request is doing the storing now
      // IT HAS TO WAIT AND GET THE RESULT LATER, BUT NOT SURE HOW TO DO IT
   }
   isStoring = true;

   ......
   // invoke a function retrieve the data from database;
   // populate allRecords array and set isStored to true
   .....
}
```

After some thinking, here is my solution.

```
var isStored = false;
var isStroing = false;
var allRecords = [];
var getSharedDataCallbacks = [];

function getSharedData(callback) {
   if (isStored) {
      callback();
      return;
   }

   getSharedDataCallbacks.push(callback);
   if (isStoring) {  
      return;
   }
   isStoring = true;

   // queryDatabase is not defined, basically, it retrieves
   // the data from database
   queryDatabase(function (error, result) {  
      var callbacks = getSharedDataCallbacks;
      getSharedDataCallbacks = [];
      isStroing = false;

      if (error) {
        callbacks.forEach(function (oneCallback) {
           oneCallback(error);
        }
        return;
      }
      allRecords = result; // assume result is an array 
      callbacks.forEach(function (oneCallback) {
          oneCallback();
      }
   });
}

function setSharedData(callback) {
    getSharedData.call(this, function (error) {
       if (error) {
          callback(error);
          return;
       }
       callback(null, allRecords);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone can give a more detailed answer, but for starters I think it could be helpful to use the [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) class that comes with Node to emit an event when beginning to retrieve the data and another when the retrieval is complete.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, but not sure how to implement it, I have decided to go with alternative solution(see above).

Comment: Looks good. For your future work in Node I would definitely recommend familiarizing yourself with `EventEmitter` since many of the core classes use it and events are often more flexible than callbacks. You can subscribe to events using the `.on()` method. But that's more of a general note; glad you found a solution.

Comment: will do, thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could help:

```
var loaded = false;
var loading = false;
var allRecords = [];

function getSharedData(callback) {
   if (loaded) {
      return callback(null, allRecords);
   }
   if (loading) {
      return (loading[loading.legnth] = callback);
   }

   loading = [callback];

   return loadData(afterLoad); //loadData is your function to load data.


   function afterLoad(err, data) {
       //process and assign to allRecords
       var i = 0
       , loadingLen = loading.length
       ;
       for(i; i < loadingLen; i++) {
         (function(cb, data) {
           cb(null, data);
         })(loading[i], allRecords);
       }

       loading.length = 0;
       loaded = true;
   }
}
```